# How to subtract values of a first column from all columns by function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I wonder how to make a function to subtract values present in column A01 from columns A02, A03 etc.

example data frame:

```
   A01 A02 A03 A04 A05 (...)
1  158 297 326 354 357
2  252 131 341 424 244
3 ...
4 ...
```

I can manually subtract each column for example:

```
sampledata[1]-sampledata[1]
sampledata[2]-sampledata[1]
sampledata[3]-sampledata[1]
sampledata[4]-sampledata[1]  ... etc.
```

But how to make a nice function to do this calculation for each of column ? As a result I suppose to have this:

```
   A01 A02 A03 A04 A05 (...)
1  0   139 168 196 199
2  0  -121 89  171 -8
3 ...
4 ...
```

After subtraction, if some value would be negative, then I want to convert it to zero.

I assume that my problem is easy to solve, but I'm newbie in R.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you tried the function `sweep()` ? `x <- matrix(1:12, 3);
sweep(x, 1, STATS = x[,1])`

Comment: Or simply `sampledata - sampledata[[1]]`. It wil recycle by column.

Comment: Or `(sampledata - sampledata[,1]) * (sampledata > sampledata[,1])` to convert negatives to zeroes

Comment: Thank you @jogo, I didn't try this function, but it looks very helpful.

Comment: The simplest and the best at this moment solution is that suggested by @mt1022, thanks!

Comment: Also answer by @DavidArenburg is very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for different solutions.
It seems that the simplest and still perfectly working is that suggested by @DavidArenburg:

```
new_sample_data = (sampledata - sampledata[,1]) * (sampledata > sampledata[,1])
```

It makes two transformations in one formula (subtracting first column, and converting negatives to zeroes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
# Your data
A01 <- c(158, 252)
A02 <- c(297, 131)
A03 <- c(326, 341)
A04 <- c(354, 424)
A05 <- c(357, 244)

df <-  data.frame(A01, A02, A03, A04, A05, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df

# Define the function
f_minus <- function(first_col, other_col) {

  other_col - first_col

}

df_output <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(df), nrow=nrow(df))) 

for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {

  df_output[,c(i)] <- f_minus(df[,1], df[,i])

}

df_output

# V1   V2  V3  V4  V5
# 1  0  139 168 196 199
# 2  0 -121  89 172  -8
```

Comment: So why not just `df - df[,1]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg to say your solution is more elegant is an understatement. Although I initially thought a function was required.